# UWP- windows.ui.xaml.controls.flipview Selection changing event?

Tags: c#, uwp, flipview

I am using `windows.ui.xaml.controls.Flipview` in my calendar control. I am doing stuff like changing the dates of the week on `SelectionChanged` event of flipview (based on the fact whether it was swipped to the right or left), since header of the week (dates) is not a part of the `flipview control`.

However, as an end-user, it does not look good to have that delay in getting those dates updated. Is there any other way to know that the flipview has started swiping? If there is, I also need to know if the flipview has been swiped to the `right` or `left` in that method or event handler since I have to show the dates for the previous or next week based on the swiping direction.

Update: I am facing the same problem in UWP application where I am using the same FlipView control. Is there any work around to this issue in UWP?

Answer (score 0):

ScrollViewer_PointerWheelChanged can be used to check weather flipping happened or not.

Can use Properties.IsHorizontalMouseWheel & Properties.MouseWheelDelta to determine the direction on which flip happened.